# Weighted count of occurrences in table (plain Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Assume I have the following table:

```
A    B    C
B    C
A    C
A
```

I want to count the frequency of each occurrence A–C but weigh it against how many occurrences there are in each row.

For this example, the weights would be 1/3, 1/2, 1/2, and 1 because there are 3, 2, 2, and 1 occurrence in each row, respectively.

Then the final calculations I'm after when doing this weighted count of A–C is:

```
A: 1/3 + 1/2 + 1 = 1,83
B: 1/3 + 1/2 = 0,83
C: 1/3 + 1/2 + 1/2 = 1,33
```

Any idea which combination of formulas must be used in order to achieve this in Excel? Please note that table has approximately 100,000 rows and 3 columns, so it is important that the calculations do not slow down the file too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, at most, only a single instance of each substring in the string, you can use `countif/numberOfSubstrings`

If the substrings might be more than one letter long, you can use

```
LEN($J$1:$J$4) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE($J$1:$J$4," ",""))+1
```

to return the number of substrings.  *If they are only on letter long, you can simplify that.*

Then, you can use:

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND(K1,$J$1:$J$4))/(LEN($J$1:$J$4) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE($J$1:$J$4," ",""))+1))
```

to return the results.

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

[image]